# General-purpose, open-source tree vizualizer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tree, treeview, debuggervisualizer

I consistently implement an [ITreeNode](http://happynomad121.blogspot.com/2011/04/net-framework-reusable-tree-operations.html) interface on all my tree structures.  It would be excellent to have a vizualizer available when debugging that would display a tree structure in a treeview.  Apart from writing my own from scratch, is there any open source vizualizer out there that could be adapted to recognize my ITreeNode interface?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JsonViewer at http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/ which provides a tree visualizer for Json String.
I have modified the same for my project use to visualize my objects as tree and you can try the same.